# android studio relative layout template has problems displaying admob ads

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, admob

The following relative layout is generated by the Android Studio 1.0.2 on linux machine.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/adFragment"
        android:name="com.gatta.e.gatta.MainActivity$AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_ad"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The admob throws warning

```
a W/Ads﹕ Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 288x488 dp.
```

and the ads are not displayed in portrait mode(landscape mode ads are displayed)

When the padding* properties of the relative layout are removed the warning is not shown and the ads are displayed.

Does removing the padding* property has any disadvantages. How to display the ads without removing the padding* properties.

Comment: Remove the padding from the relative layout. @dimen/activity_horizontal_margin is normally 16dp, 16*2 = 32 and 320 - 32 = 288.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that the padding is the issue.

Removing the padding property removes the padding, that is all.
See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html for a better understanding of Android layouts and layout properties like padding.

Why do you *want* to display the ads with padding?
If you really want padding around your Views then I suggest you create a container layout that includes all the your Views except for the AdView, and apply padding only to them.

The AdView really needs the full width of the screen (on most phones).

Comment: Solved my problem removing padding from main linearLayout